# WOL on Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 on Linux not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, wake-on-lan

I simply can't make wake-on-lan to  work on my machine. I am new to Linux so probably I am missing something. Below my config. Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

My HW Config:

```
AsRock FM2A88X-ITX+
AMD A10-7800
Running Linux Mint 17.3 64bits

BIOS configured for wake-on-lan:
    Boot From Onboard LAN: Enabled
    PCIE Device Power On: Enabled
```

My system config:

```
$ uname -a
Linux home-server 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network 
Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2110]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
        03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:10a1]
        Kernel driver in use: alx


$ modinfo alx
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
srcversion:     1917D292620190CB7319BDE
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        0C:8B:EF:E0:C1:E2:89:E4:D8:99:09:26:11:7A:DA:3B:DF:EB:41:9C
sig_hashalgo:   sha512


$ sudo ethtool eth0
    Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Current message level: 0x000060e4 (24804)
                           link ifup rx_err tx_err hw wol
    Link detected: yes


$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PB21      S4    *disabled
PB22      S4    *disabled
PB31      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:03.1
PB32      S4    *disabled
PB33      S4    *disabled
PB34      S4    *disabled
SBAZ      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.2
ECIR      S4    *disabled
PS2K      S4    *disabled
PS2M      S4    *disabled
P0PC      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.4
OHC1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:12.0
EHC1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:12.2
OHC2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:13.0
EHC2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:13.2
OHC3      S4    *disabled
EHC3      S4    *disabled
OHC4      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.5
XHC0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:10.0
XHC1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:10.1
PE20      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:15.0
PE21      S4    *disabled
PE22      S4    *disabled
PE23      S4    *disabled


$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ------HAVE_DELETED_THAT_MYSELF-----
          inet addr:192.168.1.98  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d250:99ff:fe85:92e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17749 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10035 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:22733189 (22.7 MB)  TX bytes:846896 (846.8 KB)
          Interrupt:16


$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


$ sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g
Cannot get current wake-on-lan settings: Operation not supported
  not setting wol
```

---

Additional information on Jan/22/2016 after @[MariusMatutiae](https://superuser.com/users/255732/mariusmatutiae) great inputs:

I got the latest [3.19.8 kernel](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/) and tar'ed only the Atheros alx driver (I was able to do that after following [these instructions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/qualcomm-atheros-ar8171-wake-on-lan-issues-4175491464/)):

```
$ tar xf linux-3.19.8.tar.xz linux-3.19.8/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx
$ cd linux-3.19.8/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx
$ make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` modules
$ sudo cp /lib/modules/3.19.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko /lib/modules/3.19.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko.old
$ sudo cp alx.ko /lib/modules/3.19.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
$ sudo reboot
```

The alx driver on that kernel has the WOL settings back (the only difference I noticed was the lack of the signature key on the drive -- compare the output of my 'modinfo alx' above and the one below), but no luck again!!! I am still not able to make WOL work on my machine. I have checked and re-checked everything in my BIOS setup. I can even wake it by using a USB keyboard, but not via WOL.

```
$ sudo modinfo alx
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network     Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
srcversion:     1917D292620190CB7319BDE
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
vermagic:       3.19.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

---

Additional information on Jan/30/2016

Still no luck. I was able to set the WoWLAN functionality, but no way my Linux could wake up from power-down, hibernation or suspend mode. I have tried waking it up via router and other computers in my LAN.

```
$ sudo iw phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet
$ sudo iw phy0 wowlan show
  WoWLAN is enabled:
   * wake up on magic packet
```

**The one to help me getting that to work will get a 250g pack of the finest Brazilian coffee :)**

Comment: Wake on LAN is handled by firmware, not the operating system.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but that was not actually my question. Do you have any recommendation to make it work?

Comment: What is the output of `ethtool eth0`, now?

Comment: Hi Marius, thank you again. It is still the same as above. I did some other changes but no luck yet. What I did was to install the full kernel 3.19.8, but after having some fun with my graphics card drive and some apps not working I moved back to 3.19.0. I guess Linux Mint 17.3 comes with 3.19.0 for a reason. The Brazilian coffee award is still up ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally some progress, but still not enough.  As I am on kernel "3.19.0-32-generic" I have downloaded the source code for the alx drive from kernel.org, edited the files to apply the patch ([click here for the patch](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=156751&action=diff)) as greatly advised by @MariusMatutiae, then compiled and replaced the driver with the new one patched up. Now I can finally see "Supports Wake-on: pg" in the output of ethtool command, but I can't wake the machine (shutdown, hibernate, suspend). Have tried with my router (both with the aiCloud functionality and the wake on lan native of the router) and etherwake from another linux box. I will keep digging, for now see below what I did. Another thing is that after booting the alx driver wouldn't load so I have created a script on rc.local to load it up. I am probably doing it the worst way possible, but I will get there.

Download kernel (same one I currently use)

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.19.tar.gz
```

Uncompress the alx driver files only

```
tar xf linux-3.19.tar.gz linux-3.19/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx
```

Go to the folder with the source code

```
cd linux-3.19/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx
```

**IMPORTANT**: Here it is needed to edit the alx source code files as per https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=156751&action=diff

Compile

```
sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules_install
```

Remove the alx driver (if you are remote/ssh your connection will drop and will need to login directly to the machine)

```
sudo rmmod alx
```

Re-insert the alx driver

```
sudo insmod alx.ko
```

Delete and copy the alx.ko file

```
sudo cp /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko.good
sudo rm /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
sudo cp alx.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
```

In this moment if you try "ethtool -s eth0 wol pg" it should work, however that won't last until you boot up again. So I had to add the following to my /etc/rc.local file (please notice the file created 'alx.ko' I have moved it to /Drivers/alx.ko):

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
#
exec 2> /tmp/rc.local.log
exec 1>&2
set -x
####################################################
# Enable WOL on eth0 at start-up
rmmod alx
insmod /Drivers/alx.ko
rm /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
cp /Drivers/alx.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
ethtool -s eth0 wol pg
iw phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet
# End
####################################################

exit 0
```

Comment: I guess I was just too tired last night. The above does the trick! I can wake the machine up after Powerdown and Hibernate. With Suspend does not work, but I am happy with the end results.

Comment: If i could upvote you multiple times, i would. This works for e2200 too.